# Flask: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

i am trying to execute raw sql query on my python application using heroku database.
i have created tables by running a script separately. 
[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNpGw.png)

i have configured the database as below:

```
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

when i execute INSERT INTO command i get error.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H8lI.png)

INSERT QUERY:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, firstName, lastName, email, password) VALUES (:username, :firstName, :lastName, :email, :password)",
    {"username": username, "firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName, "email": email, "password": password})
db.commit()
```

Comment: In SQL identifiers are case *insensitive*, and quoted identifiers are case *sensitive* (and can contain punctuation etc.). It looks like you have created your table using the latter, but in your INSERT statement you use the former.

Answer (score 1):

You've described the model in your code, but you didn't create tables in the database itself. Try using `db.create_all()`

Comment: i have used another python script to create tables(import.py). you can have a look at my code in github.
https://github.com/ashwinpaulallen/WebApp_Python

Comment: You've done it without application context. Try adding `with app.app_context(): ` before `db.create_all()`

Comment: Also, using create_engene is not a Flask way and using raw SQL queries is really not an SQLAlchemy way. Check this out https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-sqlalchemy-database-models/

Comment: Or here I have an example in one module https://github.com/GreenBlackSky/fun_with_flask/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy_test.py It is an example, never store your db config in code)

Comment: thanks for the tip, i am writing raw SQL as part of my learning. 
i added the change which you suggested. but after i start my application "application.py", when i register a new user i get this error. 

step 1: run "import.py" -- created all tables and imported data  
step 2: start flask application (application.py) -- here i am trying a register a new user. when i submit the user form i get this error.   

this is what i am trying to do. can you suggest something here to fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried to check columns of this table manually?

Comment: i was able to fix the issue. I used model class to create tables and then was executing raw SQL query. somehow that didnt work. i created tables using raw SQL and it worked.